# How to unbrick my Samsung Galaxy Y

Tags: unbricking, samsung-galaxy-y

I put custom ROM `ussrv8_evanlocked@ogy@xda` after rooting my Samsung Galaxy Y, and then I wanted to update kernel to overclock my phone (I followed this [set of instructions](http://mygalaxyyoung.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/overclock-samsung-galaxy-y-to-1-2ghz/)).

Now the phone is not starting. It shows

```
E:failed to mount/cache(invalid argument)
E:can't mount/cache/recovery/last_log
E:can't open /cache /recovery/last_log
```

in recovery mode. I tried to reboot, but then it shows `can't mount data/rebooting...` and the phone shows the Galaxy Y logo.

I also tried to unbrick by Odin in download mode, but whenever I'm trying to connect the phone with PC it shows "device driver is not successfully installed".

What to do?

Comment: Please help.I'm still stuck

Comment: Have you done a full wipe, reflash the ROM from recovery. You can install the USB drivers with Samsung Kies but make sure ALL kies processes are NOT running when you use ODIN. I'd say try and wipe the device and flash a ROM again from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Point 1: The error u have shown regarding cant mount **** has nothing to do with your phone bricking. Its just compilation errors in building CWM recovery (i blv this is the one u hv used)

Point 2: Unbricking by use of Odin is by far the easiest way to get ur phone back and working. This link will help you if u follow it properly [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2324937)

Point 3: Regarding your driver issue I have a solution which will definitely solve ur problem (as it worked with me thrice..!)

- Install Samsung USB drivers software which u will find in the above link.
- Put ur phone in Download mode
- Connect it to the PC
- After it fails to recognize the drivers, go to device manager and check for "Unknown" device
- Select options Manual Installation > Select from list
- Select Samsung ADB driver
- Proceed to Odin flashing...!